# Change Color of a Form on the click of a button

Tags: roblox

Basically, I am new to Roblox Exploit Development, and I want to make an exploit with the option to use a dark mode ( As the default is light )

Half of the time I have no idea what I'm doing, so my first attempt was.

```
Form1.BackColor = 40,40,40
```

That did not work. And I can't find anything on the internet to help me

How would I make it so a button can change the BackColor of a Form?

Answer (score 0):

Here u go. Just write your rgb collor into Color3.fromRGB()

```
local button = --write here path to the button
button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
 button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(49,255,90)
end)
```

Instead of button you can use whatever gui element that constains BackgroundColor3. Example2 :

```
local button = --write here path to the button
local frame = --path to the frame

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
 frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(49,255,90)
end)
```

The patch is the location of a element(like game.Workspace, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```